# How can I run all JUnit unit tests except those ending in "IntegrationTest" in my IntelliJ IDEA project using the integrated test runner?

Tags: java, unit-testing, reflection, junit, intellij-idea

I basically want to run all JUnit ***unit*** tests in my IntelliJ IDEA project (excluding JUnit integration tests), using the static suite() method of JUnit. Why use the static suite() method? Because I can then use IntelliJ IDEA's JUnit test runner to run all unit tests in my application (and easily exclude all integration tests by naming convention). The code so far looks like this:

```
package com.acme;

import junit.framework.Test;
import junit.framework.TestCase;
import junit.framework.TestSuite;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

public class AllUnitTests extends TestCase {

    public static Test suite() {
        List classes = getUnitTestClasses();
        return createTestSuite(classes);
    }

    private static List getUnitTestClasses() {
        List classes = new ArrayList();
        classes.add(CalculatorTest.class);
        return classes;
    }

    private static TestSuite createTestSuite(List allClasses) {
        TestSuite suite = new TestSuite("All Unit Tests");
        for (Iterator i = allClasses.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
            suite.addTestSuite((Class<? extends TestCase>) i.next());
        }
        return suite;
    }

}
```

The method getUnitTestClasses() should be rewritten to add all project classes extending TestCase, except if the class name ends in "IntegrationTest".

I know I can do this easily in Maven for example, but I need to do it in IntelliJ IDEA so I can use the integrated test runner - I like the green bar :)

Comment: Tagged as Java so more people will see it (don't know if it's really Java-specific, but it does use Java).

Comment: As a side-note: consider using for-each. Your for-loop would look like: for(Class testClass : allClasses) { suite.addTestSuite(testClass); }

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've written some code to do most of the work. It works only if your files are on the local disk instead of in a JAR. All you need is one class in the package. You could, for this purpose, create a Locator.java class, just to be able to find the package.

```
public class ClassEnumerator {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        List<Class<?>> list = listClassesInSamePackage(Locator.class, true);

        System.out.println(list);
    }

    private static List<Class<?>> listClassesInSamePackage(Class<?> locator, boolean includeLocator) 
                                                                      throws ClassNotFoundException {

        File packageFile = getPackageFile(locator);

        String ignore = includeLocator ? null : locator.getSimpleName() + ".class";

        return toClassList(locator.getPackage().getName(), listClassNames(packageFile, ignore));
    }

    private static File getPackageFile(Class<?> locator) {
        URL url = locator.getClassLoader().getResource(locator.getName().replace(".", "/") + ".class");
        if (url == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Cannot locate " + Locator.class.getName());
        }

        try {
        return new File(url.toURI()).getParentFile();
        }
        catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    private static String[] listClassNames(File packageFile, final String ignore) {
        return packageFile.list(new FilenameFilter(){
            @Override
            public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
                if (name.equals(ignore)) {
                    return false;
                }
                return name.endsWith(".class");
            }
        });
    }

    private static List<Class<?>> toClassList(String packageName, String[] classNames)
                                                             throws ClassNotFoundException {

        List<Class<?>> result = new ArrayList<Class<?>>(classNames.length);
        for (String className : classNames) {
            // Strip the .class
            String simpleName = className.substring(0, className.length() - 6);

            result.add(Class.forName(packageName + "." + simpleName));
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: With some modifications, mainly to make it recursive, this has worked well for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

How about putting each major group of junit tests into their own root package. I use this package structure in my project:

```
test.
  quick.
    com.acme
  slow.
    com.acme
```

Without any coding, you can set up IntelliJ to run all tests, just the quick ones or just the slow ones.

Comment: hanks. Most of the tests need to be in the same package than the class they test since they access non-public members. Whether or not that's a good practice, it can't be changed right now. So I need to keep the test and the class in the same package.

Comment: This answer would still work. test/quick and test/slow are test source roots and tests within either would still be in the com.acme package.

Comment: This is a great option. It's much easier than scraping the filesystem. It also seems to be much faster than running the tests through ant since IntelliJ only rebuilds the files that have changed.

Comment: Reply to CNelson: I created more test source roots but the trouble then is that IntelliJ only let's you group and run tests specified by package or class.

Answer (score 5):

What about using JUnit4 and the Suite-Runner?

Example:

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses({
UserUnitTest.class,
AnotherUnitTest.class
})
public class UnitTestSuite {}
```

I made a small Shell-Script to find all Unit-Tests and another one to find my Integration-Tests. Have a look at my blog entry:
http://blog.timomeinen.de/2010/02/find-all-junit-tests-in-a-project/

If you use Spring TestContext you can use the @IfProfile Annotation to declare different tests.

Kind regards,
Timo Meinen

Answer (score 0):

Spring has implemented an excellent classpath search function in the `PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver`.  If you use the classpath*: prefix, you can find all the resources, including classes in a given hierarchy, and even filter them if you want.  Then you can use the children of `AbstractTypeHierarchyTraversingFilter`, `AnnotationTypeFilter` and `AssignableTypeFilter` to filter those resources either on class level annotations or on interfaces they implement.

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/core/io/support/PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.html

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/core/type/filter/AbstractTypeHierarchyTraversingFilter.html

Answer (score 0):

Solution: https://github.com/MichaelTamm/junit-toolbox
Use the following features

```
@RunWith(WildcardPatternSuite.class)
@SuiteClasses({"**/*.class", "!**/*IntegrationTest.class"})
public class AllTestsExceptionIntegrationSuit {
}
```

assuming you following a naming pattern where you integration tests end in ...IntegrationTest and you place the file in the top-most package (so the **/*.class search will have the opportunity to pick up all your tests)