# is maven resources directory good place to put xml/json file which you are gonna read during your program?

Tags: java, maven, directory

I have a maven project where I run automated tests only. Under

```
  src/test/resources
```

I have a folder

> books

which contains 2 xml files

> (src/test/resources/books/1.xml,
>
> src/test/resources/books/2.xml).

During my test I check how many files I have in folder

> 'books'

```
int filesNumber = new File(".\\src\\test\\resources\\books").listFiles().length;
```

Everything works fine localy on my machine when I run my test with maven

> "clean test"

The problem starts when I run my tests on TeamCity server because I get a

> NullPointer

when it looks for 'books' folder.
It just can't find it. Can someone tell me why? Maybe I shouldn't put this folder to the resources directory? If yes then which directory I should use..

Answer (score 1):

It is fine to put test resource in `src/test/resources`, but don't read them as files. Read them as resources, for instance:

```
// assuming MyTest class in books package
MyTest.class.getResourceAsStream("books1.xml");
```

Or

```
MyTest.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("books/books1.xml");
```

Comment: thanks but how I can check hom many files I have?
int filesNumber = new File(".\\src\\test\\resources\\books").listFiles().length;

Comment: This is tricky. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186496/can-i-list-the-resources-in-a-given-package

Comment: You should not need a test to check the number of test resources, your tests should be directly using the 'test resources' to help test your code.