# Get classpath entries for executing web application

Tags: java, web-applications, classpath

i need to read `CLASSPATH` entries for current web application. In `CLASSPATH` i have many files with this same name. I would like to check on which position they appear in classpath. For example: `path:\file.txt;path2:\file.txt...`.

Thank you for your help.

Kind regards
Sebastian

Comment: Similar : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3923129/get-a-list-of-resources-from-classpath-directory

Answer (score 6):

Try these:

```
// get the compact classpath value
String path = System.getProperty("java.class.path");

// the character : on windows and ; on unixes
String separator = System.getProperty("path.separator");

// the character \ on windows and / on unixes
String fileSep = System.getProperty("file.separator");
```

You need the `separator` and `fileSep` because `:` and `\` are highly system-dependant.

Comment: `String path = System.getProperty("java.library.path");` that doesnt gives what i am looking for.

Comment: Edited. Try `java.class.path` instead.

Comment: I have been tried also. `String path = System.getProperty("java.class.path");` i assume it returns env variable and not variable which will be used by web application to find resources. Because i get location which doesnt contains file and the file will be founded.

Comment: I can suggest looking around in the `ClassLoader` class. You can get the instance with `ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader()`.

Comment: I'm using tomcat. I have taken `ClassLoader` and casted to `URLClassLoader`. In `URLClassLoader` i got a method `getURLs()` which gives that what i have been looking for. Tomcat has its own class loader but most of web containers class loader extends URLClassLoader so it should work.

Answer (score 5):

Using sebastian answer above, I made this piece of code, which did the trick for me.

```
ClassLoader c=getClass().getClassLoader();
logmsg("c="+c);
URLClassLoader u=(URLClassLoader)c;
URL[] urls=u.getURLs();
for (URL i : urls) {
    logmsg("url: "+i);
}
```

It gave this result:

```
classpath=/dd/apache-tomcat-7.0.29/bin/bootstrap.jar:/dd/apache-tomcat-7.0.29/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
c=WebappClassLoader
  context: /xxx
  delegate: false
  repositories:
    /WEB-INF/classes/
----------> Parent Classloader:
org.apache.catalina.loader.StandardClassLoader@35c0e45a

url: file:/DT/DEV/dev/mko/apache-tomcat-7.0.29/webapps/xxx/WEB-INF/classes/
url: file:/DT/DEV/dev/mko/apache-tomcat-7.0.29/webapps/xxx/WEB-INF/lib/commons-codec.jar
url: file:/DT/DEV/dev/mko/apache-tomcat-7.0.29/webapps/xxx/WEB-INF/lib/commons-fileupload.jar
url: file:/DT/DEV/dev/mko/apache-tomcat-7.0.29/webapps/xxx/WEB-INF/lib/commons-logging-api.jar
url: file:/DT/DEV/dev/mko/apache-tomcat-7.0.29/webapps/xxx/WEB-INF/lib/commons-logging.jar
url: file:/DT/DEV/dev/mko/apache-tomcat-7.0.29/webapps/xxx/WEB-INF/lib/freemarker.jar
url: file:/DT/DEV/dev/mko/apache-tomcat-7.0.29/webapps/xxx/WEB-INF/lib/h2.jar
url: file:/DT/DEV/dev/mko/apache-tomcat-7.0.29/webapps/xxx/WEB-INF/lib/js.jar
url: file:/DT/DEV/dev/mko/apache-tomcat-7.0.29/webapps/xxx/WEB-INF/lib/log4j-1.2.8.jar
```

Answer (score 2):

In general, your files should be in WEB-INF/lib and WEB-INF/classes - that's it.  What's the mystery?

Comment: You can also have stuff in java/endorsed and tomcat/lib which take precedence:)

Comment: I now but execution of `System.getProperty("java.class.path")` gives me for a console app or test a nice String with ; separeted entries. I would like to get this also for web application. I assume that in web application classpath is generated and `System.getProperty("java.class.path")` doesnt gives me what i want. I try this with webapplication and i get only 2 entries. With console app or test i get many many more.

Answer (score 0):

based on Rok answer, if you use Eclipse, run this code in "View" tab when you are in a breakpoint, and you will get the classpath in a file

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
java.net.URL[] urls=((java.net.URLClassLoader)getClass().getClassLoader()).getURLs();
for (java.net.URL u : urls) {
  sb.append(u+"\n");
}
org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.writeStringToFile(new java.io.File("/tmp/classpath"), sb.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created this code (hope it helps):

```java
@Slf4j
public class ClasspathLibrariesParser {
    private static final List<String> ALLOWED_KINDS = Arrays.asList("lib", "con");
    private static final SAXParserFactory PARSER_FACTORY = ClasspathLibrariesParser.createParserFactory();
    
    private static SAXParserFactory createParserFactory() {
        final SAXParserFactory parserFactory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        parserFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
        return parserFactory;
    }

    public Set<String> parseClasspathFile() {
        final File file = new File("./.classpath");
        final Set<String> paths = this.parseClasspathFile(file);
        return paths;
    }

    public Set<String> parseClasspathFile(final File file) {
        try {
            final Set<String> paths = new TreeSet<>();
            final XMLReader parser = this.createClasspathFileParser(paths);
            parser.parse(file.toURI().toURL().toString());
            return paths;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("An error happened while parsing the classpath file \"{}\". Exception: {}", file, e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
    }

    private XMLReader createClasspathFileParser(final Set<String> paths)
            throws SAXException, ParserConfigurationException {
        final XMLReader parser = PARSER_FACTORY.newSAXParser().getXMLReader();
        parser.setContentHandler(new DefaultHandler() {
            @Override
            public void startElement(final String uri, final String localName, final String qname,
                    final Attributes atts) {
                if (!"classpathentry".equals(localName) || atts == null) {
                    return;
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < atts.getLength(); i++) {
                    log.debug("read classpathentry attributes [{}] {} -> {}", i, atts.getLocalName(i), atts.getValue(i));
                }

                final String kind = atts.getValue("kind");
                if (kind != null && ALLOWED_KINDS.contains(kind)) {
                    final String path = atts.getValue("path");
                    paths.add(path);
                }
            }
        });

        return parser;
    }
}
```