# Uniform mechanism to enumerate file and Jar resources

Tags: java, url

I need to create a `Collection<URL>` from resources (files) residing in a specific folder. This folder may be accessed directly as a file: URL, or it may be contained in a jar file, accessed via a jar: URL. I know how to enumerate file: folder resources, and how to enumerate members in a jar/zip archive. I wonder if there is a uniform mechanism, saving myself the need to write the code for both cases.

Update: Note that the list of resources is not known at build time.

Comment: "..the list of resources is not known at build time."  Are you supplying these resources, or does the end user?  What are they exactly?

Comment: In this case they are XML schema resources; but it doesn't really matter. What bothers me is that I must treat file: and jar: URLs differently. It's not a big deal, I just wanted to make sure I hadn't missed anything obvious.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get a list of resources from classpath directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3923129/get-a-list-of-resources-from-classpath-directory)

Answer (score 0):

> I wonder if there is a uniform mechanism, ..

Sure:

1. Create a list of the resources (at build time).
2. Put that list at a known location.
3. Load the list to find out what resources are available, and their names.