# How to load resource from a dependency maven module

Tags: java, maven

i have a maven module *BaseProject* with java classes in `src/main/java`. Some classes are loading xml-files from the `src/main/resource` folder.
That works pretty nice.

I have a second maven project *TestProject* that has uses the *BaseProject* as dependency.
*TestProject* is my JUnit test project, so there are classes only in `src/test/java`.

If I use some of the classes from the *BaseProject* that load any resource I get a `null` because the resource file can not be found.

I assume that the `src/main/resource` folder from my *TestProject* is considered in this situation as the place to look for the resource files.

So how do i load the resource files in the *BaseProject* in a way that it will look always in its own `src/main/resource` folder?

And here is how i do it at the moment:

```
 InputStream inputStream = MyBaseClass.class
            .getResourceAsStream(
            "foo/bar/hello.xml" );
 String content = new Scanner( inputStream, "UTF-8" ).useDelimiter( "\\Z" ).next();
```

Comment: It should work. Make sure the jar of the main project (installed in your .m2 local repository) contains the XML file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getResourceAsStream("path")` looks up the resource relatively from the current class. If `foo.bar` is a full package name, you should use absolute path `getResourceAsStream("/foo/bar/hello.xml")`

Comment: Doh, layer 8 problem. Missed the maven resource plugin. Now it works. Thanks a lot

Comment: Is there anyway you could list the files under a directory? For example, something like MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/foo/bar").list() ?

Comment: @VijayRatnagiri I hope you are actually mean resources, not just files. Just google it, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3923129/get-a-list-of-resources-from-classpath-directory