# List of resources in a folder of jar file?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, resources, jar

As usually I read resources from jar file as following:

```
getClassLoader().getResource(pTextPath + "/" + pLang +".xml");
```

I need to read all resources with certain name from known folder in jar file. E.g. read *.xml from

> addon/resources/texts

Could I somehow get from jar files list of resources according to path and name template?

**UPDATE:** Exact duplication of [Get a list of resources from classpath directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3923129/get-a-list-of-resources-from-classpath-directory) Please close the question.

Comment: Put a list in the Jar when it is built.  Read that list at run-time.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3923129/get-a-list-of-resources-from-classpath-directory

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
CodeSource src = MyClass.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource();
if (src != null) {
  URL jar = src.getLocation();
ZipInputStream zip = new ZipInputStream(jar.openStream());
/* Now examine the ZIP file entries to find those you care about. */
 ...
} 
else {
   /* Fail... */
}
```

Comment: `else { /* Fail... */` At what point does the code handle the `SeurityException` potentially thrown by [`Class.getProtectionDomain()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getProtectionDomain%28%29)?