# Best practice for opening folders in Maven

Tags: maven, directory

Opening Files in Maven is best done like this:

```
Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("db.properties");
```

or this:

```
InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream("db.properties");
```

How do I open a folder in Maven and how am I able to iterate through it?

Comment: What do you mean by "in Maven"? Are you writing a Maven plugin?

Comment: or do you need something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7953600/list-of-resources-in-a-folder-of-jar-file or this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3923129/get-a-list-of-resources-from-classpath-directory?lq=1

Comment: Please see [What is the difference between Class.getResource() and ClassLoader.getResource()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6608795/what-is-the-difference-between-class-getresource-and-classloader-getresource)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming by 'in Maven' you mean 'while writing a Maven plugin'.

It usually makes sense to make file paths as configurable parameters:

```
@Mojo(name = "mygoal", defaultPhase = LifecyclePhase.PREPARE_PACKAGE)
public class MyPlugin extends AbstractMojo {
    @Parameter(defaultValue="${basedir}/src/main/resources/db.properties")
    public File dbcfg;

    @Override
    public void execute() throws MojoExecutionException, MojoFailureException {
        Properties cfg = new Properties();
        FileReader cfgReader = new FileReader(dbcfg);
        try {
            cfg.load(cfgReader);
        }finally{
            IOUtils.closeQuietly(cfgReader); 
        }
        /* .... */
    }

}
```

Note that you get to use maven expression in the default value.