# Listing resource files from a JAR

Tags: java, gradle, jar, spark-java

I have migrated a Java project to use Gradle, and it works just fine in IntelliJ or using the command line.

However when I package it into a standalone JAR using FatJar, I have some issues accessing the ressources of my project.

Here is the current code. It recursively lists the `.sql` files from the `queries` folder, and for each file it puts it in a Map.

```
private static void loadQueriesFrom(final String baseDir) throws IOException {
    final InputStream is = Queries.class.getResourceAsStream(baseDir);

    if (is == null)
        return;
    
    List<String> queryFiles = IOUtils.readLines(is, Charsets.UTF_8);
    
    for (String queryFile: queryFiles) {
        final int index = queryFile.lastIndexOf(".sql");
        
        if (index == -1) {
            loadQueriesFrom(baseDir + queryFile + "/"); // directory
        }
        else {
            final String queryName = queryFile.substring(0, index).toLowerCase();

            queries.put(baseDir.substring(QUERY_DIRECTORY.length()) + queryName, IOUtils.toString(Queries.class
                    .getResourceAsStream(baseDir + queryFile)));

        }
    }
       
}

// First call is
loadQueriesFrom("/queries");
```

My directory structure is as follows:

```
- src
  - main
      - java
      - resources
          - queries
  - test
```

This piece of code works fine except when it is packaged in a JAR: in this case, **is** (line 1) is always null. Here's my fatjar configuration:

```
task fatjar(type: Jar) {
    baseName = project.name
    from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
    with jar
    manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'My project name', 'Implementation-Version': version
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'org.mypackage.MyMainClass'
    }
}
```

If I open the .jar generated file, the structure looks like

```
- org
    - mypackage
        ...
- queries
```

So the **queries** folder *is* included in the JAR but for some reason *getResourceAsStream* can't list it. However, it can access individual files. If I insert the following line, I get the intended result.

```
Queries.class.getResourceAsStream("/queries/collaborators/get_collab_list.sql")
```

What I've tried:

- changing `/queries` to `queries`
- changing `getResourceAsStream(...)` by `getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(...)`
- both

  I've seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7953704/2215166), but it looks a bit overkill.

Help appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: take a look at this SO answer: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5193786/how-to-use-classloader-getresources-correctly/5194049#5194049](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5193786/how-to-use-classloader-getresources-correctly/5194049#5194049)
but instead of converting it to a file just use the stream of URL.openStream to read the content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn the directory resource into a File. Ignoring exceptions, in its most basic form could look something like this:

```
URL url = Queries.class.getResource("/queries");
File dir = new File(url.toURI());
for (File file : dir.listFiles()) {
    // do something with file
}
```

If you want to recurse the file tree:

```
void doSomething(File file) {
    // do something with file
}

void processFile(File file) {
    if (file.isDirectory()) {
        for (File sub : file.listFiles()) {
            processFile(sub);
        }
    } else {
        doSomething(file);
    }
}
```

then

```
URL url = Queries.class.getResource("/queries");
File dir = new File(url.toURI());
processFile(dir);
```

Comment: Hey, your solution didn't work, the File constructor threw an exception saying the URI is invalid (_not hierarchical_). I have changed the way the queries are loaded (lazy loading + caching instead of pre-loading everything). I'll give you the bounty, though, to thank you for your answer and since I can't take it back anyway. :-)

Comment: (I can't give the bounty yet, though)