# Issue to list names of files from `resources` directory. (in JAR/EXE application)

Tags: java, jar, io, resources, executable-jar

I want to randomly display .gif(s) in my application.
I would rather have my code be "self-aware" of it's content.
That's why instead of manually adding file names [like List blabla .add("/example.gif")]

This works just fine within IDE (intellij), but stopps in .jar archive.
I always struggle with similiar problems when dealing with resources, yet still can not overcome this one.

This is my class that is meant to list all .gif files that are contained in my resource dir:

```java
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ResourceHandler {
   private static final String RESOURCE_PATH = "resources";
   private static final List<String> GIF_NAMES_LIST = new ArrayList<>();

   public ResourceHandler() {
       File resourceDir = new File(RESOURCE_PATH);
       File[] files = resourceDir.listFiles();
       if (files != null) {
           for (File file : files) {
               GIF_NAMES_LIST.add(file.getName());
           }
       }
   }

   List<String> getGifNamesList() {
       return GIF_NAMES_LIST;
   }
}
```

What I am doing next in my Main:

```java
            String gifName = GIF_NAMES_LIST.get(RANDOM.nextInt(GIF_NAMES_LIST.size()));
```

What I am getting:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bound must be positive
at java.base/java.util.Random.nextInt(Random.java:322)
at Main.main(Main.java:28)

I understand that it does not read from resources, hence length of 0.
How do I modify my `ResourceHandler` class then?

Comment: Not possible. Best solution is to keep a text file (as a resource) with a listing of all the resources in it

Comment: You could try something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7953600/list-of-resources-in-a-folder-of-jar-file

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get a list of resources from classpath directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3923129/get-a-list-of-resources-from-classpath-directory)

Comment: You can’t.  There are plenty of “solutions” that make unsafe assumptions, but if you want something that’s guaranteed to work every time, make a simple text file containing all of the resource names, read that text file at runtime into a List, and pick a name from a random index in that List.

Comment: Yes, e.g. `public static Stream<String> getResourceUrls(String resourceListingUrl) {try (Scanner s = new Scanner(TheApplication.class.getResourceAsStream(resourceListingUrl)).useDelimiter("\\R")) {return s.tokens();}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seem to be a lot of misleading answers to this frequently asked question, and a lot of misconceptions about what will work.

Short answer:  **It is not possible to list application resources,** except using a ModuleReader in a named module.  A safe, universal solution is to include a text file that contains all of the resource paths.  It’s your application, so you know what’s in it at build time.

### 1. You cannot use the File class.

Your classes may not be in a directory.  They may be in a .jar file or an application image.  The File class only works on directory entries.

A .jar file is one archive file, not a directory.  The entries inside a .jar file are not files;  they are just parts of the archive, compressed data embedded with the .jar file.  They cannot be listed or read with the File class.

An application image is a single file that combines an application’s modules.  Its format is undocumented.  Attempting to understand that format is not safe, since it may change in the future without notice.  Entries in the image cannot be listed or read with the File class.

### 2. You cannot scan the .jar file.

Some solutions suggest scanning the .jar file using JarFile, JarInputStream, or the [zip file system](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/jdk.zipfs/module-summary.html).  This is not safe for two reasons:

- Using getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation() to find the application .jar file will fail eventually, because:

  - The [getCodeSource() method](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/security/ProtectionDomain.html#getCodeSource()) of ProtectionDomain may return null.
  - The [getLocation() method](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/security/CodeSource.html#getLocation()) of CodeSource may return null.
- An application is not guaranteed to be in a .jar file.  The standard [jlink](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/specs/man/jlink.html) tool produces an application image which usually does not contain .jar files.  Also, some web application containers deploy applications using a scheme which is neither a plain directory nor a .jar file.

### 3. A plain text listing file is the best approach.

It’s your application.  You already know what’s in it.  So create a plain text file that lists the path of each resource.  At runtime, you can easily read that resource:

```
Collection<String> resourcePaths;

try (BufferedReader listing =
         new BufferedReader(
             new InputStreamReader(
                 MyApplication.class.getResourceAsStream(
                     "data-file-list.txt"),
                 StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
     Stream<String> lines = listing.lines()) {

    resourcePaths = lines.toList();
}
```

It is even possible to automatically generate this listing file at build time (not at runtime), if one is proficient with certain build tools.

### 4. You can list resources in a Java module.

There is one way to safely list resources, but it only works if your application is in a named module.  You can use [ModuleReader.list()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/module/ModuleReader.html#list()):

```
Collection<String> resourcePaths;
String imagesPath = "com/example/myapp/images/";

Module m = MyApplication.class.getModule();
String moduleName = m.getName();
ResolvedModule resolved = 
    m.getLayer().configuration().findModule(moduleName).get();
try (ModuleReader reader = resolved.reference().open();
     Stream<String> resources = reader.list()) {

    resourcePaths =
        resources.filter(r -> r.startsWith(imagesPath)).toList();
}
```