How to correctly read from JarURLInputStream ? (Java)
I'm trying to read the contents of my own JAR.
With getResourceAsStream(path) I get a sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection$JarURLInputStream. But this stream seems empty, when the path is a directory.
This is my test code:
package de.CoSoCo.testzone;

import java.io.*;

/**
 *
 * @author Ulf Zibis <Ulf.Zibis@CoSoCo.de>
 * @version 
 */
public class ResourceAsStream {

  /**
   * @param args the command line arguments
   */
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String packagePath = ResourceAsStream.class.getPackageName().replace('.', '/');
    String path;
    ClassLoader cl = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    Class c = ResourceAsStream.class;
    InputStream in;
    byte [] bytes = new byte[16];
    try {
      System.out.println("path="+(
          path = packagePath));
      System.out.println("Class="+(
          in = cl.getResourceAsStream(path)));
      BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
      System.out.println("entries=");
      for (String line; (line = r.readLine()) != null; )
        System.out.println("  "+line);
      in = cl.getResourceAsStream(path);
      System.out.println("read bytes="+in.read(bytes));
    } catch (Exception ex) { System.out.println(ex); }
    try {
      System.out.println("path="+(
          path = packagePath+'/'+"A_Picture.png"));
      System.out.println("Class="+(
          in = cl.getResourceAsStream(path)));
      System.out.println("read bytes="+in.read(bytes));
    } catch (Exception ex) { System.out.println(ex); }
    try {
      System.out.println("path="+(
          path = ""));
      System.out.println("Class="+(
          in = c.getResourceAsStream(path)));
      BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
      System.out.println("entries=");
      for (String line; (line = r.readLine()) != null; )
        System.out.println("  "+line);
      in = c.getResourceAsStream(path);
      System.out.println("read bytes="+in.read(bytes));
    } catch (Exception ex) { System.out.println(ex); }
    try {
      System.out.println("path="+(
          path = "A_Picture.png"));
      System.out.println("Class="+(
          in = c.getResourceAsStream(path)));
      System.out.println("read bytes="+in.read(bytes));
    } catch (Exception ex) { System.out.println(ex); }
  }
    
}

When I run this with separate class files – e.g. inside my NetBeans IDE – I get the expected directory entries:
path=de/CoSoCo/testzone
Class=java.io.ByteArrayInputStream@4e50df2e
entries=
  A_Picture.png
  ClassFinder.class
  ClassFinder$1.class
  FileChooserDemo.class
  FileTimesFromCalendar.class
  ResourceAsStream.class
read bytes=16
path=de/CoSoCo/testzone/A_Picture.png
Class=java.io.BufferedInputStream@3941a79c
read bytes=16
path=
Class=java.io.ByteArrayInputStream@506e1b77
entries=
  A_Picture.png
  ClassFinder.class
  ClassFinder$1.class
  FileChooserDemo.class
  FileTimesFromCalendar.class
  ResourceAsStream.class
read bytes=16
path=A_Picture.png
Class=java.io.BufferedInputStream@4fca772d
read bytes=16

But when I run it from the JAR it fails:
$ java -jar TestZone.jar
path=de/CoSoCo/testzone
Class=sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection$JarURLInputStream@3d4eac69
entries=
read bytes=-1
path=de/CoSoCo/testzone/A_Picture.png
Class=sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection$JarURLInputStream@135fbaa4
read bytes=16
path=
Class=sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection$JarURLInputStream@330bedb4
entries=
read bytes=-1
path=A_Picture.png
Class=sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection$JarURLInputStream@7ea987ac
read bytes=16

To me this looks like a bug, but maybe I'm doing wrong.
My goal is to read the directory entries.

Not possible that way. You'd need to create a zip filesystem

@g00se It seems so, but why there is a InputStream instance returned instead null?

There's no guarantee what kind of stream Class::getResourceAsStream is going to return. The only thing you know is that the stream can be used to read the resource if that resource could be found and accessed by the caller. The fact a stream is returned for "directory resources" at all is not documented behavior and is known not to behave the same in all cases.

Note the way resources are accessed depends on the ClassLoader implementation. For module-aware loaders, the loader itself will typically depend on the underlying ModuleReader implementation for named modules. Accessing resources also depends on the URL mechanism, at least when using getResource(String). Which means it depends on the URLStreamHandler associated with the URL, which may depend on the configured URLStreamHandlerFactory.  And then it depends on the implementation of URLConnection returned by the handler.

As for the difference in behavior you observe, when running your code from NetBeans, your code is likely being run directly from the file system (i.e., it's not packaged in a JAR file first). This means you're accessing the resource via a FileURLConnection (an internal class). And that class has apparently implemented getInputStream() to return a stream that gives you the names of a directory's children when the file is a directory. When your code is packaged in a JAR, you get a JarURLConnection, which doesn't work the same way. Though again, most of this is all implementation details.

If your objective is to list resources so you can choose from among them for loading then one trick you can pull is to make a text file index of them and load that. That's not a problem as you will know what the resources are when you build it. Since resources are read-only they will only change if you build it again with different ones. IOW, you always know what you've got in there

You cannot list a resource directory, because it’s not really a directory.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77863392/issue-to-list-names-of-files-from-resources-directory-in-jar-exe-application/77866868.

You are all right with the reasons, why it doesn't work, but I still think, returning a non-functional InputStream instead of null or an Exception, is a bug.
In the mean time I found a very smart solution -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/32828953/5399598

Depending on which tool you used to create the jar file, you’ll have zero length entries for the directories in the file. The I/O API reflects exactly that. You’ll get null if no such entry is present or an empty input stream when a zero length entry is present. I don’t consider using the Compiler API for such a task “very smart”. That’s like building a rocket to fly to the next supermarket. Further note that the relevance of the “context loader” is a tenacious myth. The method getContextClassLoader() of a thread will just return whatever has been set via setContextClassLoader(…).

@Holger Thanks for explaining about the I/O API, which I didn't know, where to find.
I created the JAR with NetBeans IDE. I think, they use the "normal" jar tool. But which alternatives are out there?
And which tool you suggest, if Compiler API is not appropriate?

You can use the FileSystem API which allows operations like Files.list(…). See this answer, for example.

@Holger Thanks for your inspiration. A little exhaustive, because of much use of streams, and not collecting recursively. Using less streams makes the code more compact and probably faster, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78751388/5399598

@CoSoCo the great thing about using the FileSystem API is that you can choose what to do with the paths. If you want to recurse, just use walk instead of list. I don’t see your point about streams, you are still using the method returning a stream and eagerly collecting the stream into a list before iterating it is not faster than iterating the stream in the first place.

@Holger The possibility of walk I've overseen. Thanks for the hint. Iterating the stream in the first place becomes exhaustive, when I want to do more than System.out.println(p);, e.g. a function like Class.forName(), which throws exceptions, which I want to handle outside the stream iteration. Also I have to define an additional interface and invoke an accept() method.

Another problem is, when there are more than 1 classpaths (some retrieving resources from standard files, some from a JAR file). Then Paths.get(MyClass.class.getResource("MyClass.class").toURI()).getParent() is not enough.

The additional interface in that answer is for encapsulating the action, so that the method can be reused for different actions. That’s why the solution is introduced as “the most general solution”. This has nothing to do with the Stream API at all. If you have only a single task and do not want to reuse the method, you can omit this abstraction, of course. Then, it’s not a general solution anymore, but for your specific task, it’ll be more concise, sure. But how should I be able to provide a solution for your specific task eight years ago? That’s why the answer uses an abstraction.

@Holger Now I updated my answer, using Files.walk(). Unfortunately there is no way to 1. avoid the Files.isDirectory() check and 2. avoid following links.

Here is another solution without using the StandardJavaFileManager, which finds all resources as well as all classes from a package and it's sub-packages recursivly. It works on file system files and JAR packaged as well mixed.
To avoid the Files.isDirectory() check use Files.walkFileTree().
package de.CoSoCo.testzone;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.nio.file.attribute.BasicFileAttributes;
import java.util.*;

/**
 *
 * @author Ulf Zibis <Ulf.Zibis@CoSoCo.de>
 * @version 
 */
public class ResourceList {

  private static final String PACKAGE = ResourceList.class.getPackageName();
  // A sorted set of resource names of this package:
  protected static final Set<String> RESOURCES = new TreeSet<>();
  // A sorted set of subclasses of this package
  protected static final Set<Class> CLASSES = new TreeSet<>(Comparator.comparing(Class::getName));

  /**
   * Scans all resources accessible from the context class loader which belong to
   * the current package and subpackages.
   */
  static {
    try {
      for(Enumeration<URL> res=ResourceList.class.getClassLoader().getResources(PACKAGE.replace('.','/'));
          res.hasMoreElements(); ) {
        URI uri = res.nextElement().toURI();
        try {
          collectResources(Paths.get(uri));
        } catch (FileSystemNotFoundException fe) {
          try (FileSystem fs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(uri, Collections.<String, Object>emptyMap())) {
            collectResources(Paths.get(uri));
          }
        }
      }
    } catch (Exception ex) { ex.printStackTrace(); }
  }

  private static void collectResources(Path path) throws IOException {
    try (var stream = Files.walk(path, FileVisitOption.FOLLOW_LINKS)) {
      stream.forEach(p -> {
        if (Files.isDirectory(p, (LinkOption)null))  return;
        RESOURCES.add(p.toString());
        try {
          String name = p.toString().replace(File.separatorChar, '.').replaceAll(".*(" + PACKAGE + ".*)", "$1");
          if (name.endsWith(".class")) {
            CLASSES.add(Class.forName(name.substring(0, name.length() - ".class".length())));
          }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | NoClassDefFoundError ex) { System.err.println(ex); }
      });
    }
  }

  // Alternative:
  private static void collectResources2(Path path) throws IOException {
    Files.walkFileTree(path, new SimpleFileVisitor<>() {
      @Override
      public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
        RESOURCES.add(file.toString());
        String name = file.toString().replace(File.separatorChar, '.').replaceAll(".*(" + PACKAGE + ".*)", "$1");
        if (name.endsWith(".class"))  try {
          CLASSES.add(Class.forName(name.substring(0, name.length() - ".class".length())));
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | NoClassDefFoundError ex) { System.err.println(ex); }
        return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
      }
    });
  }

  /**
   * @param args the command line arguments
   */
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (String str : RESOURCES)
      System.out.println("resource path "+str);
    for (Class clazz : CLASSES)
      System.out.println(clazz);
  }
}


Don’t use Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader(). If you want to get classes in the (sub) packages of ResourceList.class’s package, you should use ResourceList.class.getClassLoader(). The context class loader is a property anyone can set to an arbitrary value entirely unrelated to the package(s) you are looking for. Further, the separator for getResources has to be '/', not File.separatorChar.

By the way, you can simplify url -> { urls.add(url); } to url -> urls.add(url) or even urls::add. Alternatively to walk, you can use walkFileTree and extend SimpleFileVisitor and override visitFile  which is only invoked for non-directory files, so no isDirectory is needed then

@Holger Thanks for your hint. Am I correct, that after Paths.get(uri) I still have tu use File.separatorChar, as on Windows it could be '\'?
I will change the code accordingly.

@Holger I had considered to use walkFileTree, but I didn't find a good example, how to code a FileVisitor. Do you have one? I do not understand, which action to put into visitFile.

@Holger In the javadoc of walkFileTree I also read: "The visitFile method is invoked for all files, including directories, encountered at maxDepth ...". So why you think, diretories are skipped?

Directories are not skipped, the preVisitDirectory and postVisitDirectory methods are called for directories. And the documentation says explicitly: “If the file is not a directory then the visitFile method is invoked with the file attributes.”

Paths.get(uri) uses an URI which will use a / for hierarchical URIs. In case of Paths.get(String), you’d use the platform specific character, i.e. File.separatorChar or FileSystems.getDefault().getSeparator(). However, Windows has no problems when you use a / instead. It’s more important to fulfill expectations (regarding how a path looks like) when interacting with the user…

@Holger So the documentation is self-contradictory, see some passages later
(In hope, this special text-quoting link will work for you, as Firefox ignores it.)

In my understanding, preVisit... and postVisit... do not mean visit.... So as there is no vistitDirectory, it seems that all files are meant by visitFile.
And your cited phrase just describes one case, but does not exclude the other cases, e.g. directory.

"If it is not raining, I do a walk." does not mean, that I never do a walk, when it is raining.

The sentence is not contradicting, if you don’t cut it the way you did. It says “The visitFile method is invoked for all files, including directories, encountered at maxDepth,” which is a special case. If you decide to to provide a small number for maxDepth such that it can ever be reached (unlike the default of Integer.MAX_VALUE) then, the directories at the maximum depth, which will not be traversed, are treated like ordinary files. I’m using this method for almost a decade now, I know what it is doing, I don’t know where your attempts to discuss the wording are heading at.

@Holger Thanks for your correction. English is not my mother tongue, so I misinterpreted that sentence. So now I have tested walkFileTree and can confirm, that it works as you say. With walkFileTree the code is much more compact than with the stream variant walk.

You may simplify further by using new TreeSet<>(Comparator.comparing(Class::getName)) and instead of .asIterator().forEachRemaining(…) resort to the (very) old loop variant, for(Enumeration<URL> res = ResourceList.class.getClassLoader() .getResources(packageName.replace('.', '/')); res.hasMoreElements(); ) { URI uri = res.nextElement().toURI(); … } which eliminates the need for exception handling within the loop body.

@Holger  The squirrel feeds labouriously, thanks and updated.

Here is a solution using the StandardJavaFileManager, which finds all resources as well as all classes from a package and it's sub-packages.
It works on file system files and JAR packaged as well mixed.
package de.CoSoCo.testzone;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.tools.*;
import static javax.tools.JavaFileObject.Kind.*;

/**
 *
 * @author Ulf Zibis <Ulf.Zibis@CoSoCo.de>
 * @version 
 */
public class ResourceList {

  // A sorted set of resource names of this package:
  protected static final Set<String> RESOURCES = new TreeSet<>();
  protected static final Set<Class> CLASSES // A sorted set of subclasses of this package
      = new TreeSet<>((Class o1, Class o2) -> o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getName()));

  /**
   * Scans all classes accessible from the context class loader which belong to
   * the current package and subpackages.
   */
  static {
    String packageName = ResourceList.class.getPackageName();
    StandardJavaFileManager fm = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler().getStandardFileManager(null, null, null);
    try {
      for (JavaFileObject file : fm.list(StandardLocation.CLASS_PATH, packageName,
          new TreeSet<>(Arrays.asList(SOURCE, CLASS, HTML, OTHER)), true)) {
        RESOURCES.add(file.getName()
            .replaceAll(".*("+packageName.replace('.', File.separatorChar)+".*?)\\)*$", "$1"));
      }
      for (JavaFileObject file : fm.list(StandardLocation.CLASS_PATH, packageName,
          Collections.singleton(CLASS), true)) {
        try {
          CLASSES.add(Class.forName(file.getName().replace(File.separatorChar, '.')
            .replaceAll(".*("+packageName+".*)\\.class.*", "$1")));
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | NoClassDefFoundError ex) { System.err.println(ex); }
      }
    } catch (Exception ex) { ex.printStackTrace(); }
  }

  /**
   * @param args the command line arguments
   */
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (String str : RESOURCES)
      System.out.println("resource name "+str);
    for (Class clazz : CLASSES)
      System.out.println(clazz);
  }
    
}

