# Save all files from a folder in a jar

Tags: java, file, jar, resources, directory

First:

I know, this question was asked about 100 times already.
I know, someone already could have gave the right answer.

But anyway, I have to ask this again. I didn't found a solution working for me. sorry.

I'm writing a game in java. Of course I have many packages (folders) with sounds and pictures and so on. But these folders are each of variable size. So I want to save the content of such a folder dynamically in a list.

Usually, I was making this:

```
File f[] = new File(getClass.getResource("/home/res/").toURI()).listFiles();
```

Now I can iterate though this file object and save each file. Perfect. Really?

No. When I extract this Project into a jar archive, this fails. All because a uri isn't "hierarchical" or some stuff like this. See this exception:

```
C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop>java -jar Homework.jar
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not hierarchical
        at java.io.File.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at homework.moonface.src.Moonface.loadSounds(Moonface.java:94)
        at homework.moonface.src.Moonface.<init>(Moonface.java:55)
        at control.Overview.main(Overview.java:16)
```

Ok, I thought, so I need to get this path and add it manual into the file object. (new File("path"); But... this doesn't work. I'm getting the known error that the input wasn't written correctly, or when i try to cut of "file:" from the resource url, it breaks because in a jar its "jar:file:" and not "file:". But also if I cut of jar:file: I'm getting null.

So, please don't mark this as a duplicate, and try to explain this shortly for me. It would help thousand other, who don't understand other solutions who aren't solutions.

Comment: Don't ask for pity and don't suck-up. If you ask a proper question with proper details (like it seems you have), someone will help you.

Comment: Just to be clear: you have a jar with a bunch of files that you want to write to the file system?

Comment: Time to learn `Ant`. With Ant scrip you can manage all your resources

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis my hole project is in the jar. (double click file) main class, other classes and resources.

Comment: I dont suck up, i just want to ask for pardon because of this question, which was asked already...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3923129/get-a-list-of-resources-from-classpath-directory

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
    URL jarResourceURL = getClass().getResource("/home/res/");
    JarURLConnection jarURLConnection = (JarURLConnection) jarResourceURL.openConnection();
    Enumeration<JarEntry> entries = jarURLConnection.getJarFile().entries();
    while (entries.hasMoreElements()){
        entries.nextElement(); // iterate over entries and do something
    }
```

**UPD:** I was thinking about how spring framework's `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext` resolves the resources from jars. So i investigated the source code and foud that there is an utility class `org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource` which have a convenient interface (moreover there is a possibility to get the corresponding `java.io.File` instance using it) and can help you to solve the problem. Here is the doc : 
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/core/io/ClassPathResource.html

Comment: getting this exception:


`java.lang.ClassCastException: sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection cannot be cast to java.net.JarURLConnection at homework.moonface.src.Moonface.loadSounds(Moonface.java:93)
 at homework.moonface.src.Moonface.<init>(Moonface.java:55)
 at control.Overview.main(Overview.java:16)`

Comment: Did you tried to work with classpath member which is not in jar ?

Comment: not, but the resources have to be in the jar.. or what do you mean?