# Access src/main/resources/ dynamically from source code

Tags: java

My files are located under `projectRoot/src/main/resources/levels/`

[image]

If I call `Utils.getFileNamesInDirectory("src/main/resources/levels")`, it works.
But when project is packaged, `levels` directory is placed under `root` of `.jar`.
How can I made this dynamic in static class? i.e `src/main/resources/`
So that code will run within eclipse and as standalone jar.

Code to list files in directory ..

```
public class Utils {
    public static List<String> getFileNamesInDirectory(String directory){

        List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();

        File[] files = new File(directory).listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
            public boolean accept(File dir, String filename) {
                return filename.endsWith(".json");
            }
        });

        for (File file : files) {
            if (file.isFile()) {
                results.add(file.getName());
            }
        }

        Collections.sort(results);

        return results;
    }
}
```

**Updated**

I've moved to using `getResourceAsStream` (as `getResource` was causing `IllegalArgumentException: URI is not hierarchical`) and I'm able to list files in a directory within `Eclipse`.

```
public static List<String> getFileNamesInDirectory(String directory){

        List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
        InputStream in = Utils.class.getResourceAsStream("/" + directory);
        BufferedReader rdr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        String line;

        try {

            while ((line = rdr.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println("file: " + line);
                results.add(new File(line).getName());
            }

            rdr.close();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        Collections.sort(results);

        return results;
    }
```

But when I run it as standalone .jar  I get the following error on this line: `while ((line = rdr.readLine()) != null) {`
Why does it not work outside `Eclipse`?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:322)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:364)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:210)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:205)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:165)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:328)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:393)
    at com.app.tools.Utils.getFileNamesInDirectory(Utils.java:31)
```

Comment: You don't. `/src/main/resources` is a **project** directory convention used by Maven to contain resources that will end up at the root of a generated archive/classpath.

Comment: In, eclipse you should also use the classpath rather than the file system.

Comment: I'm aware `src/main/resources` is a directory convention for `Maven`. Do you have example of classpath use over filesystem?

Comment: See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason your code works in Eclipse is that Eclipse launches the `java` process from the project directory and we can assume the path provided in

```
Utils.getFileNamesInDirectory("src/main/resources/levels")
```

is relative to the current working directory (the project directory). Since the file system location `<project-directory>/src/main/resources/levels` exists, it can be found and returned to you.

`src/main/resources` is a Maven convention meant to hold resources that will eventually end up in the classpath when the project is compiled/built/deployed. To retrieve resources from the classpath you use `Class#getResource(String)`, `ClassLoader#getResource(String)` and/or `ClassLoader#getSystemResource(String)`.

Now, [although there are ways to list resources in the classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3923129/get-a-list-of-resources-from-classpath-directory), you should not typically do this. If you need a resource, you know it by name and can therefore use one of the methods listed above to get it.

Comment: I'm no longer using file system approach, instead using `getResourceAsStream` but still having issues, any ideas? updated question

Comment: @bobbyrne01 `getResourceAsStream` returns `null` if no matching resource can be found. Does your `.jar` contain the resource at the right (specified) path?

Comment: The .jar has folder at `/levels` i.e the root of .jar. I'm passing `/levels` to `getResourceAsStream`

Comment: @bobbyrne01 A directory does not constitute a resource. Is `/levels` a directory or a file entry in the `.jar`?

Comment: `/levels` is a directory contains 3 files i.e `level1.json`, `level2.json` and `level3.json` .. all of which are in the .jar

Comment: @bobbyrne01 So, you can access `/levels/level1.json` and the others as resources.

Comment: But I first need to list the filenames before I can access them, which is failing stated above, as the filenames are dynamic.

Comment: @bobbyrne01 See the link in my answer. But you really shouldn't be accessing resources dynamically from the classpath.