# ApplicationContext.getResources - path pattern issue

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, glassfish

Stupid problem, but I can't solve it. Java server - glassfish 4. I have in WEB-INF tiles**.xml files. For example I have tiles.xml, tiles2.xml (I can have more in future) and I need to get them. I use the following code

```
Collection<ApplicationResource> webINFSet = 
applicationContext.getResources("/WEB-INF/tiles*.xml")
```

However it this code returns only one.

```
System.out.println("Size:"+webINFSet.size());//out Size:1
```

Where is my mistake?

Comment: Sure this is JavaEE and not Spring?

Comment: @Thomas I use Glassfish 4.

Comment: Can you post the FQCN for ApplicationContext, i.e. the package as well?

Comment: @Thomas org.apache.tiles.request.ApplicationContext

Comment: @Thomas I'm sorry that's interface. I think it will take a long time to find its implementation. Could you say how can I get what I want by JavaEE means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at [org.apache.tiles.request.servlet.ServletApplicationContext at GrepCode](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.tiles/tiles-request-servlet/1.0.5/org/apache/tiles/request/servlet/ServletApplicationContext.java#ServletApplicationContext.getResources%28java.lang.String%29), which I assume is the implemenation you get, it seems as if the error (if there is any) is not on your side. The implementation looks like this:

```
public Collection<ApplicationResource> getResources(String path) {
  ArrayList<ApplicationResource> resources = new ArrayList<ApplicationResource>();
  resources.add(getResource(path));
  return resources;
}
```

Depending on what you need, you could try and look for the files on the classpath. There is, however, no standard way of searching for resources by name pattern, but you could have a look here: [Get a list of resources from classpath directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3923129/get-a-list-of-resources-from-classpath-directory)