# Walk through files in a directory throwing NoSuchFileException

Tags: java, classpath

I'm using the following code to try to walk through all the .class files in the current classpath, however it is throwing a NoSuchFileException before iterating once. Am I doing something wrong?

```
Enumeration<URL> systemResources = ClassLoader.getSystemResources("");

        while (systemResources.hasMoreElements()) {
            String fileName = systemResources.nextElement().getPath();
            Stream<Path> filter = Files.walk(new File(fileName).toPath()).filter(Files::isRegularFile);
            Consumer<Path> renameMe = (path) ->
            {
                System.out.println(path.toString());
            };
            filter.forEach(renameMe);
        }
        ;
```

Comment: You're looking for all the files named *empty string* in the classpath. Of course such a file does not exist.

Comment: It's my understanding that this is how I get the classpath. Am I wrong on this?

Comment: No. There is nothing in the documentation nor the source code that indicates this should be so. Have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3923182/4125191) to a similar question.