# read structure of resources folder from inside of a jar

Tags: java, jar, clojure, classpath

Is there a way to read out the whole structure of the resources folder in a leiningen project?

It looks like this one only works, when the project is not yet packed into a jar:

```
(require '[clojure.java.io :as io])

(-> (io/resource "")
    io/file
    file-seq)
```

Particularly, in a packed jar `(io/resource "")` already returns nil instead of a valid Java object.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get a list of resources from classpath directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3923129/get-a-list-of-resources-from-classpath-directory)

Comment: I have suggested the existing question which handles the same problem (using Java API).