# Is the directory listing behaviour of getResourceAsStream documented anywhere?

Tags: java

Various answers (e.g. [Get a list of resources from classpath directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3923129/get-a-list-of-resources-from-classpath-directory)) indicate that if you call `getResourceAsStream` on a directory, the returned stream will contain a list of items in the directory, one per line. This doesn't appear to be documented in the [ClassLoader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)) Javadoc. Is it specified anywhere else, or is it just an implementation detail that people have come to rely on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't look like this is appropriately documented anywhere.

From the Javadoc of `ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream` you can somewhat infer that `getResourceAsStream` is the same as doing `getResource` and then calling `URL.openStream` on the resulting URL, because the Javadoc points to the `getResource` method, which returns `URL`. But its clearly not spelled out to that degree of accuracy.

> `public InputStream getResourceAsStream(String name)`
>
> Returns an input
>   stream for reading the specified resource. The search order is
>   described in the documentation for `getResource(String)`.

Then, `URL.openStream` is documented better:

> `public final InputStream openStream() throws IOException`
>
> Opens a connection to this URL and returns an InputStream for reading
>   from that connection. This method is a shorthand for:
>        `openConnection().getInputStream()`

Then, since `URL.openConnection()` returns a subclass of `URLConnection`, and assuming that you used a local directory in your classpath, you need to look at `FileURLConnection`, and then in the method [`getInputStream`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/sun/net/www/protocol/file/FileURLConnection.java#FileURLConnection.getInputStream%28%29).

As you can see in the method below, if the `file:///` URL from the classpath points to a directory, then it returns an `InputStream` with all the files in the directory in a sorted manner. (Interesting detail, it uses the platform default encoding - good to know when you want to read the data back)

```
public synchronized InputStream getInputStream()
    throws IOException {

    int iconHeight;
    int iconWidth;

    connect();

    if (is == null) {
        if (isDirectory) {
            FileNameMap map = java.net.URLConnection.getFileNameMap();

            StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();

            if (files == null) {
                throw new FileNotFoundException(filename);
            }

            Collections.sort(files, Collator.getInstance());

            for (int i = 0 ; i < files.size() ; i++) {
                String fileName = files.get(i);
                buf.append(fileName);
                buf.append("\n");
            }
            // Put it into a (default) locale-specific byte-stream.
            is = new ByteArrayInputStream(buf.toString().getBytes());
        } else {
            throw new FileNotFoundException(filename);
        }
    }
    return is;
}
```

### Conclusion:

It's not properly documented, it's an implementation detail, it could change in future releases, although that's not likely.

Comment: Thanks, and that also explains why you can't list directories in JAR files in this manner: the [JarURLConnection](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/sun/net/www/protocol/jar/JarURLConnection.java?av=f) class doesn't have that functionality.