# How to read all filenames in a classpath directory with Tomcat 8.5?

Tags: java, classpath, tomcat8

I have some code that reads all filenames from a classpath directory which uses the following:

```
Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("myClasspathDir/");
```

Recently we migrated to Tomcat 8.5 and this stopped working. The [Apache changelog](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/changelog.html) states that:

> Fix:  When calling getResourceAsStream() on a directory, ensure that
>   null is returned. (markt)

I need an alternative to read the files from the classpath (**no absolute path**). We do not use Spring in this application. It is a simple Java application.

Any thoughts on how to get the filenames from a classpath directory? I know there are lots of related answers but they usually use Spring, absolute paths to directories or other solutions that are not applicable.

Comment: You need to create your own Scanner
See previously ask https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3923129/get-a-list-of-resources-from-classpath-directory