# Java Code: Missing classpath from webapp but no issues in desktop app

Tags: java, web-applications, classpath

I am trying to read the property filenames under my resources folder (src/main/resources) with the below code

```
final String classPath = System.getProperty("java.class.path", ".");
System.out.println(classPath);
```

Above code is working perfectly file in a desktop application but in web application above System.out.println is giving me this output:

---

```
/C:/Development/INSTALLED/apache-tomcat-8.0.46/bin/bootstrap.jar
/C:/Development/INSTALLED/apache-tomcat-8.0.46/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
/C:/Program%20Files/RedHat/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.151-1/lib/tools.jar
```

(missing \target\classes)

While running the same code on desktop app I am successfully getting "\target\classes" where I can see the properties file.

What change should I do to read the names of those files via classpath? Please help.

[image]

Comment: To answer your question, please take a look at your `WAR` file, and check if it contains those class files.

Comment: Yes they are there in /WEB-INF/classes folder

Comment: What is the second param "." at `("java.class.path", ".");`

Comment: You can just ignore that. Removing that part also giving same output in both the apps

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved this by google relection api. But I am still open for other solutions.

Add dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.reflections</groupId>
    <artifactId>reflections</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.11</version>
</dependency>
```

Java code:

```
Reflections reflections = new Reflections("translation", new ResourcesScanner());
final Set<String> fileNames = reflections.getResources(pattern);
```