# Unable to get a resource when running an main class or test in sbt

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm trying to run a test that uses a resource in sbt. The test depends on a util that loads a resource via `ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream(...)`, which results unexpectedly in `null`. If I run the same test in Intellij or via bazel, the test succeeds. I additionally performed a test by creating a main class to list all resources according to the `ResourceList` example given in an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3923129/get-a-list-of-resources-from-classpath-directory), and this confirmed that that file and many others were inaccessible at runtime.

These resources are not contained in the `resources` directories that sbt usually uses; they are contained in a jar file that is included in the `lib` directory. The sources in my project built by sbt depend heavily on this jar, and compilation is successful, so it appears the issue may be specific to resources. One thing I noticed is that the resource can be loaded if I use a `ClassLoader` object and call `getResourceAsStream` instead of using the static method `ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream`.

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue (short of copying out all resources from the jar file in `lib`)?

Comment: Did you tried [this](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.0/docs/Howto-Customizing-Paths.html#Change+the+default+resource+directory) ?

Comment: That looks like instructions for setting resources that are defined as part of the project itself. I'm trying to include resources that are included in a jar that is in the `lib` directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running tests in [forked JVM](https://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Forking.html#Enable+forking):

```
Test / fork := true
```

[Unmanaged dependencies](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Library-Dependencies.html#Unmanaged+dependencies) in `lib/` should end up by default on all the classpaths, including `test`, without having to do anything special:

> Dependencies in `lib` go on all the classpaths (for `compile`, `test`, `run`,
>   and `console`).

Note, when running tests in IntelliJ you might be using IntelliJ's internal build system as opposed to SBT shell, which could be the reason why it worked in IntelliJ. To run tests in IntelliJ via sbt shell, select [`Use sbt`](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-and-test-scala.html#test_scala_app) checkbox in `Edit Configurations...`

I would suggest using [`getClass.getResourceAsStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream-java.lang.String-), as this anyways uses *system* `ClassLoader` as [fallback](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/lang/Class.java#l2203):

```
     public InputStream getResourceAsStream(String name) {
        name = resolveName(name);
        ClassLoader cl = getClassLoader0();
        if (cl==null) {
            // A system class.
            return ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream(name);
        }
        return cl.getResourceAsStream(name);
    }
```