# How to get classpath resources by extension?

Tags: java, classpath, classloader

Suppose I've got a few resource files in my classpath:

```
/a/b/c/x1.txt
/a/b/d/x2.txt
/a/b/e/x3.txt
```

My code does not know the full paths of these resource files. It knows only their extension `.txt`.
How would you write a function to return the paths of the resources with extension `.txt` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Path path = Paths.get(YourClass.class.getResource("/resources").toURI());

List<String> result = Files.find(path, 100,
        (p, a) -> p.toString().toLowerCase().endsWith(".txt"))
        .map(Path::toString)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Would it work for _classpath resources_ but not just files in the file system ? The resource files might be stored in a jar added to the classpath.

Comment: No, I don't. Would prefer not to add dependencies.

Comment: Ok, there is a library which could help you with that.

Comment: Do you mean Spring or another library ?

Comment: Spring has a class for this kind of task: PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver. See if this response could help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3923129/get-a-list-of-resources-from-classpath-directory

Comment: Great. Thanks a lot. I will definitely take a look.