# Get Random File from Folder - Java

Tags: java

I have a Spring Maven project I'm trying to load a random file from a folder in `classpath` but I'm getting nullpointer in `files`

Folder I want -> `src/main/resources/images/common/`

Why `classpath:` is not being interperted? How can I fix my code?

```
File[] files = new File("classpath:images/common/").listFiles();

private byte[] getRandomFile() throws IOException {
    Random rand = new Random();
    File file = files[rand.nextInt(files.length)]; //null pointer
    return Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath());
}
```

I also tried

```
ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
URL url = loader.getResource("images/common/");
String path = url.getPath();
File[] files = new File(path).listFiles();


private byte[] getRandomFile() throws IOException {
    Random rand = new Random();
    File file = files[rand.nextInt(files.length)];
    return Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath());
}
```

Comment: The `File` object is for naming files on the *file system*. The classpath is not a file system.

Comment: check my edit. This also gives me null pointer

Comment: Make a list of the items to choose from, count the list, generate a random number between 0 and count-1, pull that item from the list using the random index.  Works for nested files, files in a directory, customer records, or anything.  Good luck!

Comment: As per @EdwinBuck, and as you have shown you already know how to select a random element of list, you just need to correctly get the list of files (which is the problem in your code). This is covered in great length in the answers to question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3923129 .