# Unable to load resource folder in Java

Tags: java, maven

I am trying to open a Folder called Images within my resource folder, however it is returning null.

`ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();`

`URL url = loader.getResource("Images");`

`File f1 = new File(url.toString());`

When looking deeper into the issue I see that when calling `f1.canRead()` is returning false. When I looked up the file permissions it says that the folder has "Full control" Access. I made sure that the resource folder is "marked as resource folder" in Intellij. Any advice is appreciated. A link to the full code can be found here https://github.com/Software-Engineering-Final-Project/articleFetch/blob/master/src/main/java/com/articlefetch/app/Busniess/Service/ImageServiceImpl.java

Comment: Use `getResourceAsStream("/...")` and don't use File cause within a jar you can't use file.

Comment: If `Images` is a directory, consider this question & its answers:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3923129/get-a-list-of-resources-from-classpath-directory

Comment: @khmarbaise Thank you!