# How to access the excels sheets while running the Jar file inside it and copy outside jar?

Tags: java, file, jar

I have a Jar file which has many excel sheets inside it. I want to access the excels sheets while running the Jar file and copy somewhere. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You can access the Excel sheets as resources in the classpath:

```
Class.getResourceAsStream("/excelfiles/myfile.xlsx");
```

For reading Excel sheets in java you can use [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) library

If you only want to copy the files to an output folder (without understanding Excel, you can just read the resource as an `InputStream` and write it to a a `FileOutputStream`.

Comment: My problem is that there are 100s of excel file inside a folder with subfolders (say "excelFolder") and I need to get the names of all excel files .I can not hard code the excel file names.

Comment: This may help:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3923129/get-a-list-of-resources-from-classpath-directory to scan the resources in a folder of the classpath.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is resolved. I used below code to access the excels inside jar and copy excels outside my Jar

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    final String classPath = "Path_Of_Jar/abc.jar";
    JarFile jarFile = new JarFile (classPath);

    String copyFolderExcel="Path to copy excels";
    File excelFolderFile = new File (copyFolderExcel);
    excelFolderFile.mkdir();

    Enumeration<JarEntry> e = jarFile.entries ();
    while (e.hasMoreElements ()) {
        JarEntry entry = (JarEntry) e.nextElement ();

        if (entry.getName ().contains ("excelFiles/")) {
            String name = entry.getName ();

            if(name.contains (".xlsx")) {
                copyExcel(jarFile,name,copyFolderExcel);

            }
      }
    }
jarFile.close ();
}

private static void copyExcel(JarFile jarFile, String file,String updatedFolder) throws IOException {


    String[] outputFileName = file.split ("/");
    String finalName = outputFileName[outputFileName.length-1];

    JarEntry entry = (JarEntry) jarFile.getEntry(file);
    InputStream input = jarFile.getInputStream(entry);
    OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream (updatedFolder+"/"+finalName);


    try {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[input.available ()];
        for (int i = 0; i != -1; i = input.read (buffer)) {
            output.write (buffer, 0, i);
        }
    } finally {

        input.close();
        output.close();
    }
}
```

}