# Error to deploy war in tomcat with multitenant org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Error during file deployment

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, tomcat8, multi-tenant

Excuse me for my bad english,

I have the following code, made with spring boot 2.4. Use as Ide Eclipse with Spring Tools. Allows you to take from a folder three documents called db1.properties db2.properties, etc.

```
        @Configuration
    public class MultitenantConfiguration {
        
        @Autowired
        private DataSourceProperties properties;
        
        @Bean
        @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.datasource")
        public DataSource dataSource() {
            File[] files = Paths.get("src/main/resources/tenants").toFile().listFiles();
            Map<Object,Object> resolvedDataSources = new HashMap<>();
            
            for(File propertyFile : files) {
                Properties tenantProperties = new Properties();
                DataSourceBuilder dataSourceBuilder = DataSourceBuilder.create(this.getClass().getClassLoader());
                try {
                    tenantProperties.load(new FileInputStream(propertyFile));
                    
                    String tenantId = tenantProperties.getProperty("name");
                    
                    dataSourceBuilder.driverClassName(properties.getDriverClassName())
                    .url(tenantProperties.getProperty("datasource.url"))
                    .username(tenantProperties.getProperty("datasource.username"))
                    .password(tenantProperties.getProperty("datasource.password"));
                    
                    if(properties.getType() != null) {
                        dataSourceBuilder.type(properties.getType());
                    }
                    
                    resolvedDataSources.put(tenantId, dataSourceBuilder.build());
                    
                }catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
    
                    return null;
                }
            
            }
            
            MultitenantDataSource dataSource = new MultitenantDataSource();
            dataSource.setDefaultTargetDataSource(defaultDataSource());
            dataSource.setTargetDataSources(resolvedDataSources);
            
            dataSource.afterPropertiesSet();
    
            return dataSource;
        }
        
        private DataSource defaultDataSource() {
            DataSourceBuilder dataSourceBuilder = DataSourceBuilder.create(this.getClass().getClassLoader())
                    .driverClassName(properties.getDriverClassName())
                    .url(properties.getUrl())
                    .username(properties.getUsername())
                    .password(properties.getPassword());
    
            if(properties.getType() != null) {
                dataSourceBuilder.type(properties.getType());
            }
    
            return dataSourceBuilder.build();
        }
    
    }
```

When I compile my project I have no error. But when I deploy it in tomcat it shows me the following

```
21 19:22:18.728 INFORMACIÓN [http-nio-8090-exec-62] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Despliegue del archivo [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\redlinev12v2-2.war] de la aplicación web
15-Jan-2021 19:22:26.087 INFORMACIÓN [http-nio-8090-exec-62] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars Al menos un JAR, que se ha explorado buscando TLDs, aún no contenía TLDs. Activar historial de depuración para este historiador para una completa lista de los JARs que fueron explorados y de los que nos se halló TLDs. Saltarse JARs no necesarios durante la exploración puede dar lugar a una mejora de tiempo significativa en el arranque y compilación de JSP .
15-Jan-2021 19:22:30.588 GRAVE [http-nio-8090-exec-62] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Error durante el despliegue del archivo [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\redlinev12v2-2.war] de la aplicación web
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error starting child
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:720)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:690)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:706)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:978)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:493)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1642)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:288)
        at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1596)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.upload(HTMLManagerServlet.java:294)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doPost(HTMLManagerServlet.java:212)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:652)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter.doFilter(CsrfPreventionFilter.java:211)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:126)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:667)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.RequestFilterValve.process(RequestFilterValve.java:348)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve.invoke(RemoteAddrValve.java:53)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:690)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:888)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1597)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/redlinev12v2-2]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:717)
        ... 47 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [com/softdelsur/redlinev12/MultitenantConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:229)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1356)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1206)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:571)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:531)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:410)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1336)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1179)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:571)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:531)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1159)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:588)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:144)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:767)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:426)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:326)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:173)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:153)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:95)
        at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:174)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5166)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        ... 48 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [com/softdelsur/redlinev12/MultitenantConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:658)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:486)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1336)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1179)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:571)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:531)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1367)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1287)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791)
        ... 80 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653)
        ... 94 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.softdelsur.redlinev12.MultitenantConfiguration.dataSource(MultitenantConfiguration.java:34)
        at com.softdelsur.redlinev12.MultitenantConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d986e6f.CGLIB$dataSource$0(<generated>)
        at com.softdelsur.redlinev12.MultitenantConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d986e6f$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$266f86a6.invoke(<generated>)
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331)
        at com.softdelsur.redlinev12.MultitenantConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d986e6f.dataSource(<generated>)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
        ... 95 more
15-Jan-2021 19:22:30.590 INFORMACIÓN [http-nio-8090-exec-62] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\redlinev12v2-2.war] has finished in [11.862] ms
```

I do not know how to move forward if I comment the Bean works well, I tried to locate the file in another path but I continue in the same way. I hope your help

Comment: The stack trace says the NullPointerException occurred on line ~43~ (EDIT: oops, 34) of MultitenantConfiguration.java. Which line is that?

Comment: line 34, but yes, you need to tell us which line that is.

Comment: Looks like this code assumes the tenant config files are on the filesystem under `src/main/resources/tenants`... and this is not true when the app is deployed.

Comment: Instead of assuming they're on the filesystem, perhaps you could load them using [`PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/support/PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.html) or one of the other techniques mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3923129/get-a-list-of-resources-from-classpath-directory

Comment: @dnault line 34 takes file by file and allows me to read the content  for(File propertyFile : files) . This following your advice on using PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver, I'll be commenting shortly

Answer (score 1):

The problem is solved by changing the way to find the configuration files

```
Map<Object,Object> resolvedDataSources = new HashMap<>();
        PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver resourceLoader = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver();
        try {
            Resource[] resources = resourceLoader.getResources("/tenants/*.properties");
            for (Resource resource : resources) {
                try{
                System.out.println("Este es el recurso: "+resource);
                Properties tenantProperties = new Properties();
                DataSourceBuilder dataSourceBuilder = DataSourceBuilder.create(this.getClass().getClassLoader());
                File templateFile = resource.getFile();
                
                tenantProperties.load(new FileInputStream(templateFile));
                String tenantId = tenantProperties.getProperty("name");
                
                dataSourceBuilder.driverClassName(properties.getDriverClassName())
                .url(tenantProperties.getProperty("datasource.url"))
                .username(tenantProperties.getProperty("datasource.username"))
                .password(tenantProperties.getProperty("datasource.password"));
                
                if(properties.getType() != null) {
                    dataSourceBuilder.type(properties.getType());
                }
                
                resolvedDataSources.put(tenantId, dataSourceBuilder.build());
                }catch (IOException e) {
                    System.out.println("Fallo al abrir los archivos de db");
                    e.printStackTrace();

                    return null;
                }
            }
            
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Archivo de configuración no encontrado");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

use PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver as commented @dnault