# Copy out files in resources folder

Tags: java, embedded-resource

I use Gradle to manage a Java project. In C# I'm able to set a number of files as embedded resource and access them at runtime.

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#sec:java_project_layout says `src/main/resources` is for Production resources, such as XML and properties files. Therefore I put my resource files there.

[image]

Now how do I access and copy out these files in my Java code?

Many posts talk about classpath, `user.dir`, or sort of things. I don't know what they are, but I specifically only deal with these files in the resources folder.

I tried https://stackoverflow.com/a/3923182/746461, it lists thousands of files, which looks like too powerful, and I don't know what is the best way to limit the scope.

Besides, I also need my program to copy out these exact files to, say `C:\tmp`, and keep the folder structure. How would I do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to list the files inside a JAR file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1429172/how-to-list-the-files-inside-a-jar-file)

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar I'm not talking about jar. As Code-Apprentice answered, Gradle does not include these files in jar. I'm fine with puting them to jar, just advise me how to do it. I merely need to copy out a bunch of embedded things.  I don't care how they are embedded, in jar or in a separate folder.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell you can read them directly from `resources/...`. The gradle doc that you linked also explains that the resources directory is copied to `$buildDir/resources/$name` when the project is built. So the compiled project will be able to access the same relative path.

Comment: Can you give some code? I'm too new to Java to figure out the correct way of saying "relative".

Comment: @Gqqnbig "relative path" is a general file system concept and has nothing to do with Java specifically.