# Read a bunch of JSON file from a folder in Java

Tags: java, json, file-io, filesystems

I was trying to read a bunch of JSON files in a Java class.
I tried this

```java
InputStream is = Myclass.class.getResourceAsStream("/data");
InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(is);
BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(in);
Stream<String> lines = bufferedReader.lines();
```

I got a `Stream<String>` which contains the a bunch of Strings of the JSON file name. I got all the JSON name strings, but how can I access to each JSON, like transfer each JSON to an object or else operations

Here is my package structure

```
src
--MyClass.java
data
--One.json
--Two.json
--Three.json
```

Comment: Instead of giving `getResourceAsStream` the path to the directory, give it the path to one of the files. You'll need to do this for each resource.

Comment: yeah, make sense. but I was wondering how I can loop the folder, any Java method to do so

Comment: Not as straightforward as you might hope: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3923129/get-a-list-of-resources-from-classpath-directory Can you merge all your files into a single JSON file with a known name?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly you only want to read all the `.json` files which are inside some folder.

You can use `java.nio` package to traverse through all the files and achieve the same easily. 
Example:
Folder Strucure

```
src
--java files
data
--subfolder
   --abc.txt 
--another.txt
--one.json
--two.json
```

To traverse through `data` folder and fetch only `.josn` files

```
String dir =System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/data";
                    
try{
    List<Path> paths = Files.walk(Paths.get(dir),1) //by mentioning max depth as 1 it will only traverse immediate level   
                            .filter(Files::isRegularFile) 
                            .filter(path-> path.getFileName().toString().endsWith(".json")) // fetch only the files which are ending with .JSON
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    //iterate all the paths and fetch data from corresnponding file                                 
    for(Path path : paths) {
        //read the Json File . change here according to your logic
        String json = new String(Files.readAllBytes(path));
    }           
}catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Need to read individual files instead of the directory as 'tgdavies' suggested.

```
Path dir = Paths.get("data");
    
try (DirectoryStream<Path> stream = Files.newDirectoryStream(dir, "*.json")) {
    for (Path p : stream) {
        
        BufferedReader buffReader = Files.newBufferedReader(p);
        
        // rest of reading code ...
    }
}
```

Or reading all lines using java.nio.file.Files

```
Path dir = Paths.get("data");

try (DirectoryStream<Path> stream = Files.newDirectoryStream(dir, "*.json")) {
    for (Path p : stream) {
        
        Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(p);
        String data = lines.collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator()));
        
        // rest of code logic ...
        lines.close();
    }
}
```