# Parameterized test for each file

Tags: android, testing

I'm searching for a way to have a parameterized test based on the content of a folder
Since it's an Android test I am a bit limited in the test tools I can use

Idea is: i add a file to the folder -> one more test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't look much different from any other parametrized test (`@ParametrizedTest`). The sample program can look like this (for simplicity everything is in one file):

```
class SomeFunction {
    fun doStuff(parameter: String): Int {
        return parameter.length // production code to be tested
    }
}

class SomeFunctionTest {

    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        fun testData(): Collection<String> {
            // for simplicity of the demo reading the whole file into string
            return File("testfolder").listFiles().map { it.readText() }
        }
    }

    @ParameterizedTest
    @MethodSource("testData")
    fun testDoStuff(testInput: String) {
        println("running test: $testInput")
        assertEquals(testInput.length, SomeFunction().doStuff(testInput))
    }
}
```

You source your test data from a `testfolder`. If you want to get the data not from the file api but rather as classpath resources - that's another story - there are some suggestions like this: [Get a list of resources from classpath directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3923129/get-a-list-of-resources-from-classpath-directory)

Comment: Indeed, had to tweak it a bit for my case linked with android but this helped a lot
@JvmStatic
        @Parameterized.Parameters(name = "{0}")
        fun data() = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().context.assets.list("folder")!!
            .filterNot { it.endsWith(".json") }
            .map {
                arrayOf(it.substring(0, it.lastIndexOf(".")), it.endsWith(".pdf"))
            }