# Best practice for loading resources from directory

Tags: java, junit

I have a JUnit test of a Java class `com.example.business.ContentEvaluator` where I want to load different resources to verify some method `public boolean isGreat(byte[] content)`. There are two parameterized tests, one that tests behavior where the method is expected to return `true` and another one where the expectation is to return `false`.

In the test resource folder `src/test/resources/com/example/business/`, there are now 2 subfolder `trueContent` and `falseContent` containing ~5 resource files each that I want to load in the test.

What is the best practice to load these resource in my unit test?

The options that I see:

1. List all files in the given subfolder and load there contents. Example:

   ```
   Files.list(Paths.get(ContentEvaluatorTest.class.getResource("trueContent").toURI()))
   ...
   String testedContent = Files.readString(file)
   ```

   New files are automatically picked up by the test, but you cannot see that a file is used by the code, because the filename is never written down in the code. Additionally, this option relies on the presence of file system (ability to convert a resource into an actual file/path). Is this a good assumption to have for JUnit tests?
2. Have the resource filenames in a list inside the test and iterate over these to not rely on the file system. Example:

   ```
   private static final List<String> TRUE_CONTENT_FILENAMES = Arrays.asList("data1.pdf", "bigData.csv", "small.txt");
   ...
   for (String resourceFilename : TRUE_CONTENT_FILENAMES) {
     String testedContent = new String (ContentEvaluatorTest.class.getResourceAsStream("trueContent" + resourceFilename ).readAllBytes(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
   }
   ```

   Searching for the resource file name will reveal the test where the resource is used, but if the resource file set is adjusted in any way (file added/removed/renamed), the String list needs to be adjusted as well.

Which option is better? Or is there some other option that is better than both of them?

Comment: Try creating dynamic tests using `@TestFactory`, `DynamicContainer` and `DynamicTest`. That allows you to create nested tests and use file names as container or test names.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not solve the question if I should go for option 1 or 2 on how to iterate over my resources.. It's just an alternative to using parameterized test, which is not what I'm asking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible, albeit a little less performant, to retrieve resources from your classpath (see [SO:3923129](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3923129/get-a-list-of-resources-from-classpath-directory)), and might be worth considering.  That said, I don't imagine you're likely to encounter a situation in which you would be running unit tests in an environment that has no file system, and your technique is cross-platform compatible.

I would argue for option 1 in that it is less complicated to maintain.  I would make a point of failing the test if it can't find any test data.