# Getting the names of all Java classes declared in a package

Tags: java, class, package

I'm writing a functionality where it would be helpful to get the classes inside a certain package of my program. Also, I only want the classes that subclass a certain class.

I need the classes in order to call static methods on them.

Is there an automatic way to do this? If so, is it slow?

In case I was not clear, what I want is something like this:

```
ArrayList<Class<? extends MySuperClass>> classes = ;

classes.add(MyClass.class); 
classes.add(MyClass2.class);
```

Instead of having to call add for each class, I would like to automatically get that class list.

The number of classes is small, so I would not mind declaring them manually if the automatic trick would be slow - this app is for a mobile platform.

In either way, I would also like to know how to call the static method for each method in the ArrayList:

```
  // error The method nameOfStaticMethod is undefined for the type Class<capture#2-of ? extends MySuperClass>
  classes.get(0).nameOfStaticMethod ();
```

Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 2):

Java doesn't provide this ability. There is no introspection at the package level. The classes could be records in a database, or on the other side of a network connection. There's no requirement for them to be stored and organized so as to facilitate enumerating them by package.

You could make a custom class loader and API to provide a method of listing the class names.

Comment: Could yo provide a description why this ability is not included / would be hard to implement?

Comment: The classes may be records in a database, or on the other side of a network connection. There's no requirement for them to be stored and organized so as to facilitate enumerating them by package.

Comment: Frummeled your comment into the answer ("frummeled" is Dutch slang, which I think should be used in English as well, meaning: made it fit somehow, after a lot of "frummeling").

Answer (score 1):

I too would like to list all classes in a package but so far the methods of doing this is pretty bad:

- **Like JOTN suggested** - needs file access - not if it is a jar
- **Listing a JAR entries** - well, also needs the jar file

Quoting a [older](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176527/how-can-i-enumerate-all-classes-in-a-package-and-add-them-to-a-list) SO question:

> It isn't possible to query a Package for it's Classes (or even its subpackages). http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=341935&start=0&tstart=0 contains a very good discussion about why this is problematic, as well as a handful of solutions to your problem.

Anyways, here is how you invoke static methods on the class:

```
Method m = Integer.class.getMethod("toString", Integer.TYPE);
System.out.println(m.invoke(null, 123));
```

Comment: Link unfortunately broken and given the state of the Oracle website in general, hard to track down.

Comment: This could be the broken link: https://community.oracle.com/message/7520168#7520168