# How to prevent multiple instances of a Java annotation in a class

Tags: java, annotations

I have a Java annotation type like this:

```
import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.METHOD;
import static java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME;

import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target(METHOD)
public @interface Foo {

}
```

My intention is to avoid multiple instances of this annotation. In other words I want to disallow the next example code and throw an exception:

```
public class FooTest {
   @Foo
   public void method1(){...}
   @Foo
   public void method2(){...}
}
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: U can definetly use Refelction to see if more than one Method has the Exception also you could check at compile time for this https://medium.com/@jintin/annotation-processing-in-java-3621cb05343a

Comment: Annotation has no effect unless there is an annotation processor for it. So you have to implement a processor - that could be done with Reflection API as @Alex suggested

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prevent launching multiple instances of a java application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7036108/prevent-launching-multiple-instances-of-a-java-application)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best technique to fulfill your intention (*avoid multiple instances of this annotation*) would be a static check, simply because it can be done and would detect the problem earlier. This is supported through Java's [annotation processing feature](https://cloudogu.com/en/blog/Java-Annotation-Processors_1-Intro).

However, the question also shows a desire to do this at run-time given that it includes `@Retention(RUNTIME)` and mentions exceptions. This can be done easily with reflection *if the list of classes to check is known in advance*. Here's a simple piece of code to check one class, since the question mentions checking a single class.

```
public static void checkClass(Class<?> clazz) {
    boolean used = false;
    for( Method method : clazz.getDeclaredMethods() ) {
        if( method.getAnnotation(Foo.class) != null ) {
            if( used ) { 
                throw new IllegalFooUseException(); 
            }
            else { used = true; }
        }
    }
}
```

Checking across a project would be more work, as it would require collecting all the classes in the project, which [isn't so simple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172866/getting-the-names-of-all-java-classes-declared-in-a-package).