# In Java, how can I construct a File from a resource?

Tags: java, file-io

File takes String and URI in its constructors.

`getClass().getResource(...)` returns URL and 
`getResourceAsStream(...)` returns InputStream. Is there a way to construct a File from a resource?

Comment: What would you expect it to do if it represented a resource within a jar file? There's no `File` object representing that.

Comment: Are you trying to pass the `File` to some API that does not accept a stream?

Comment: Why do you need a `File`?  Is this resource for read only, or read/write?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't. At least not in the standard case where the resource is inside a Jar. Java File Objects must point to actual file system objects (files and folders), whereas a resource is an entry in a Jar File. Trying to construct a File from a Jar resource URI will result in an exception:

> `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException`: URI is not hierarchical

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to construct a File from a resource?

Strictly speaking, no. But if you really need a File (to pass to an API), then you can create a temporary file and write the InputStream to that.