# How to get list of resource files?

Tags: java

I am able to read a particular resource into an InputStream.

```
InputStream inputStream = MyClass.getResourceAsStream("/resources/test.xml")
```

But I cannot get a list of all resource files in the resources package for some reason.

I have tried the code from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10994416/2170281) to no avail.

Edit: I am only interested in getting a list of the file names from the resources package.

Edit 2: The code is called from a runtime eclipse instance.

Comment: @HemantPatel That won't give you a list of resources

Comment: @HemantPatel - there is no relative path passed

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get a list of resources from classpath directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3923129/get-a-list-of-resources-from-classpath-directory)

Comment: What exactly is the "resources package" ? Is this a directory ? packaged in a JAR ? Where is it located ?

Comment: @yunandtidus It is a package located directly under src. Here is a screenshot. https://i.imgur.com/MSXarMZ.png

Comment: There is no single line solution to your problem, you should take a look at answers in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3923129/get-a-list-of-resources-from-classpath-directory (pointed out by @JanOssowski)

Answer (score 2):

Most of the answers to this question presume that the resource is being found as a 'loose' (not in a Jar) file on the local file system. But once deployed, those types of things will likely be inside a Jar and any use of the `File` class will fail to act as a file (because it's not).

To get a listing from inside a Jar, insert a textual list into the Jar at build time that lists each other resource of interest. At runtime, load the list, then proceed from there.

Comment: I believe that the OP's linked answer does a brute force iteration of `JarEntry` objects if the resource is not a directory